# How can I consume a Json Payload from a webhook and display certain features of the Json in vb.net MVC?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jira, webhooks

I am currently working on an ASP.NET visual basic MVC application that will consume a webhook that has been fired from **JIRA** when it has been fired, then it will display certain bits of that information in the application.

So far I have successfully got the Webhook to fire successfully and the Webhook URL is going to RequestB.in and it will send the Json Payload (currently to RequestB.in) and I can see that it is working.

Then using the Json that it has sent to I converted it to VB.Net classes using Paste Json as Classes  (this is the information that I want to display):

```
Public Class JiraWebhookObject
   'properties 
End Class

Public Class Issue
  'properties 
End Class

Public Class Fields
'Properties
End Class

Public Class Issuetype
    'Properties
End Class

Public Class Priority
    'Properties
End Class

Public Class Status
    'Properties
End Class

Public Class Project
    'Properties
End Class

Public Class Comment
    'Properties
End Class

Public Class Comment1
    'Properties
End Class
```

I then created an API controller to connect it to the class like this:
    Public Class ValuesController
         Inherits ApiController

```
'GET api/values
Public Function [Get]() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
End Function

'GET api/values/5
Public Function [Get](id As Integer) As String
    Return "value"
End Function

'POST api/values
Public Sub Post(<FromBody> JiraWebhookObject As String)

End Sub  

End Class
```

But how do I display this in the application for every Json Payload that is fired.  I am trying to deserialize the data like this:

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0
Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
Using reader = New StreamReader(Request.InputStream)

         Dim json = reader.ReadToEnd()
         Dim contentType As String = Request.ContentType
         Dim body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)

   Try
         Select Case DirectCast(body.key, String)
             Case ""
                'Return json(success = True)
             Case Else
                'Return json(New With {Key .success = True, Key .message = "Some message"})

            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Using
```

But in the Switch statement I am unsure of how to display the Json in a correct format.  Do I have to use an event to display this Json data and how can this be done?

Do I need to retrieve it from the RequestB.in URL like this:

```
    Private Shared Sub test()

        Dim task = MakeRequestJira()
        task.Wait()

        Dim response = task.Result
        Dim body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

    End Sub
    Private Shared Async Function MakeRequestJira() As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
       Dim httpClient = New HttpClient()
       Return Await httpClient.GetAsync(New Uri("http://requestb.in/x9xnl8w9"))
    End Function
```

Could I have the Webhook URL firing to my application (what URL should I specify) and then use that to retrieve the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got the Json Payload from the Webhook URL:

```
Function URLEndpoint() As ActionResult

        Dim r As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream)
        Dim jsonAs String = r.ReadToEnd()
        Dim issue As oject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of object)(json)
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(json)
```

Then create the classes to have the correct information from the Webhook:

```
Public Class object
    Public Property issue As Issue
    <DataMember(Name:="Timestamp")>
    Public Property timestamp As Long
    Public Property comment As Comment3
End Class
```

Then you can do what you want with the data after that for example display it or send it on via email